# Customized shape in Fabric - how to draw beyond it's size?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I need to draw customized rectangle - the one with 4 "ears" in each corner.

[image]

So I defined my own class based on `fabric.Object` like this:

```
var CustomRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {
...
}
```

Important note: when creating objects based on my class `CustomRect` I want to define `width` and `height` as a size of a rectangle **without** those "ears".

But I have a problem. **I can not draw outside of an area** defined by *width x height*.

Everything else gets clipped - it's drawn but not visible. So I'm not able to draw those "ears" while they go beyond the limits of an area width x height.

How to tell fabric to extend drawing area? How can I draw outside of *width x height* area?

Many thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried using a group with a rect and four circles?

Comment: add an executable snippet or the code of your custom object, please

Comment: @Ben Good idea. But I would like to easily modify object's size by setting width/height and in group it would be not so easy. Need to move circles accordingly... Can group receive events like "modified" to adjust circles in some automatized way?

Comment: An example of what you have so far would be pretty handy at this point.

Answer (score 2):

So I have found this solution. Not perfect but it works.

While Fabric adjusts the size of painting area for an object according to it's `width` and `height` parameters, I had to make my own width and height parameters.

Fabric's width and height are set to the size of **painting** area, while my width and height are set to the real size of a rectangle (rectangle without "ears").

Here we go, class definition first:

```
var CustomRect = fabric.util.createClass(fabric.Object, {

    initialize: function(options) {

        options || (options = { });

        if (options.width || options.height){
            alert('Do not use width/height, use my_width/my_height instead.');
        }

        // here we set our Object's width, height to create painting area for it
        // It must be little larger than rectangle itself to paint "ears"
        options.width = options.my_width + SIZE_EXTEND;
        options.height = options.my_height + SIZE_EXTEND;

        this.callSuper('initialize', options);
    },

    _render: function(ctx) {

        var PIx2 = 6.28319; // 2 * PI
        var w_half = (this.width - SIZE_EXTEND) / 2;
        var h_half = (this.height - SIZE_EXTEND) / 2;

        ctx.rect(this.left, this.top, this.width - SIZE_EXTEND, this.height - SIZE_EXTEND);
        ctx.fill();
        // "ears"
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(-w_half, -h_half, 4, 0, PIx2, false);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(w_half, -h_half, 4, 0, PIx2, false);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(-w_half, h_half, 4, 0, PIx2, false);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(w_half, h_half, 4, 0, PIx2, false);
        ctx.fill();
    }
}
```

`SIZE_EXTEND` is a constant defined elsewhere (for my application constant is OK).

And now how I use it in my application. Adding a new rectangle onto my canvas:

```
    var TheCanvas;

    TheCanvas = new fabric.Canvas('mainCanvas');
    TheCanvas.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    TheCanvas.setHeight(window.innerHeight);

    TheCanvas.add(new CustomRect({
        left: 500,
        top: 200,
        my_width: 100, // here I define size WITHOUT "ears"
        my_height: 100
    }));
```